# CSS for all class under a tag

Tags: css, class

I have html like this

```
<div>
    <ul class="reportTable reportTableSum">
        <li class="rowW">
            <ol class="class_one">1</ol>
            <ol class="class2">2</ol>
            <ol class="classiii">3</ol>
            <ol class="class4">4</ol>
            <ol class="classfive">5</ol>
            ...[and more class]
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I need to setup css part like this for those html. class name are random and not in numeric order.

```
.reportTable li ol.class_one,
.reportTable li ol.class2,
.reportTable li ol.classiii,
.reportTable li ol.class4,
...,
.reportTable li ol.classfive{
    display:block;
    min-height:15px;
    padding:1px 15px 1px 2px;
    margin:0;
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I try to re-write the css to something like this or similar to apply for all the class but it does not seem work

```
.reportTable li ol.*{
    ...
}
```

How can I make this work. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the rule to be apply, in the given context, to all such `ol` elements  that have a `class` attribute, no matter what its value is, use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
.reportTable li ol[class]
```

A selector of this kind is well supported (even IE 7).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the wildcard `*`. Furthermore `ol.*` is invalid syntax.

Use the following:

```
.reportTable li ol {
  // add declarations
}
```